# How to change a GPIO to output and high on 64bit ARM (aarch64)?

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, gpio

I had some working GPIO routines which I used on many RPi boards (32bit).

Recently I tried moving onto 64bit and I'm cross-compiling with this prefix:

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-
```

However, I can't change any of the GPIO pins (neither mode, neither value) with this little C code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

#define DT_SOC_RANGES                           "/proc/device-tree/soc/ranges"
#define DEV_MEM                                     "/dev/mem"
#define IO_MEM_BASE_OFFSET                  4
#define GPIO_BASE                                 (physIOMemBase + 0x00200000)

// GPIO Memory Addresses
#define GPIO_FSEL0                              (0x00/4)
#define GPIO_SET0                               (0x1c/4)
#define GPIO_CLR0                               (0x28/4)
#define GPIO_LEV0                               (0x34/4)
#define GPIO_PULLEN                             (0x94/4)
#define GPIO_PULLCLK                            (0x98/4)
#define GPIO_BANK(pin)                          (pin>>5)

#define ERROR_INITPERMAPS_MEMBASE           7
#define ERROR_INITPERMAPS_MAP                   8

static uintptr_t physIOMemBase;     // Physical IO memory base
static volatile uintptr_t* virtGPIOMemBase; // Virtual GPIO memory base

uintptr_t getPhysIOMemBase() {
  // the start address is a 32bit BE unsigned integer at offset 4 in /proc/device-tree/soc/ranges

  std::ifstream f(DT_SOC_RANGES);
  if (!f.is_open()) {
    return 0;
  }

  f.seekg(IO_MEM_BASE_OFFSET);
  uint8_t bytes[4];
  if (!f.good() || f.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(bytes), sizeof(bytes)).bad()) {
    return 0;
  }

  // the value is stored as big endian
  return static_cast<uintptr_t>(
    (static_cast<uint32_t>(bytes[0]) << 24) |
    (static_cast<uint32_t>(bytes[1]) << 16) |
    (static_cast<uint32_t>(bytes[2]) << 8) |
    (static_cast<uint32_t>(bytes[3])));
}

volatile uintptr_t* mapPeripheral(uintptr_t base) {
  int fd = open(DEV_MEM, O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
  void* vaddr;

  if (fd < 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  vaddr = mmap(NULL, getpagesize(), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, base);
  if (vaddr == MAP_FAILED) {
    return 0;
  }

  close(fd);
  return (volatile uintptr_t*)vaddr;
}

int initPermaps() {
  physIOMemBase = getPhysIOMemBase();

  if (!physIOMemBase) return ERROR_INITPERMAPS_MEMBASE;

  virtGPIOMemBase   = mapPeripheral(GPIO_BASE, GPIO_LEN);

  if (!virtGPIOMemBase) return ERROR_INITPERMAPS_MAP;

  printf("Physical base address = %lx\n\n", physIOMemBase);

  printf("Mapped peripherals into virtual memory:\n");
  printf("GPIO base virtual address = %p\n", virtGPIOMemBase);

  return 0;
}


void gpioSetPinMode(int pin, int mode) {
    uintptr_t fsel = virtGPIOMemBase[GPIO_FSEL0 + pin/10];
    fsel &= ~(7 << ((pin % 10) * 3));
    fsel |= mode << ((pin % 10) * 3);
    virtGPIOMemBase[GPIO_FSEL0 + pin/10] = fsel;
}

int gpioReadPin(int pin) {
  if ((virtGPIOMemBase[GPIO_LEV0 + GPIO_BANK(pin)] & (1 << (pin & 31))) != 0)
       return 1;
  else
       return 0;
}

void gpioWritePin(int pin, int value) {
    if (value) {
         virtGPIOMemBase[GPIO_SET0 + GPIO_BANK(pin)] = 1 << (pin & 31);
    }
    else {
         virtGPIOMemBase[GPIO_CLR0 + GPIO_BANK(pin)] = 1 << (pin & 31);
    }
}

}

int main() {
   initPermaps();
   gpioSetPinMode(29, 1);
   gpioWritePin(29, 1);

   sleep(5);

   return 0;
}
```

Earlier, on the 32bit machines I had the above code running with some slight diffs:

```
static uint32_t physIOMemBase;     // Physical IO memory base
static volatile uint32_t* virtGPIOMemBase; // Virtual GPIO memory base
```

So, the above code with `uint32_t` variables can run perfectly on 32bit RPis, but not on 64bit ones.

Therefore I wanted to finetune it, but I couldn't succeed, and I'm seeking the reason, on why this is not working on 64bit.

Here is the BCM2837's peripheral datasheet: https://cs140e.sergio.bz/docs/BCM2837-ARM-Peripherals.pdf, register details start on page 90, in section 6.1.

Comment: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=283456 suggests that the "parent address" at offset 4 in `/proc/device-tree/soc/ranges` is a 64-bit address under aarch64.  Indeed, on my machine, as a 64-bit address (big-endian) it would be `0x00000000fe000000` which matches what I see in dmesg.  You didn't share the output of your code, but are you seeing 0 for "Physical Base Address"?  That should be a red flag.

Comment: By the way, `be64toh` from `<endian.h>` is probably easier than your chain of `static_cast` and shifts.  Or, since you are in C++, `std::byteswap`.

Comment: If you use `dev/gpiomem` instead of `dev/mem` you don't need any address calculation, as you are already in the register address block.

Comment: Don’t use that or _/dev/gpiomem_ as suggested, all comments above are not root causing it, i.e. that don’t tell you about correct ABI one should use with a Linux kernel. The proper way is to open _/dev/gpiochipX_ and perform ioctls on it. You may find `libgpiod` helping you with this.